# How do I access bus decals DLC?

Tags: persona-5

Atlus released two free DLC items on the PSN store which allow you to customize your bus you drive around in Mementos. I downloaded the DLC and I do not receive any items that allow me to customize my bus?

What do I do to use these DLC packs on my bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the bus decal DLC packs in Persona 5 you have to enter Mementos. While in the main lobby you have to go to the turnstile you use to enter Mementos and you will see a new option which is to customize your bus. If you downloaded both packs you should see three options, one for the Phantom Thieves decal, one for the 20th anniversary decals, and the third for the default bus design.